# Admin menu success message

Tags: wp-admin, jquery, menus

I have created a simple admin menu that allows users to enter in some basic information that is stored in the footer.

When they click save the url appends `&settings-updated=true`

Is there a way, using jQuery to show a success/fail message?

Can anyone show me how or give me an example?

Thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the top answer on this Stackoverflow question. Basically you need to use:

```
decodeURI((RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]);
```

[Get URL parameter with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403888/get-url-parameter-with-jquery)

Comment: Hi thanks, I'm not that technically able, could you help decode or explain how the actual code would need to work?